# Figuring out why Date.parse() does not equal comparison date

Tags: javascript, date

When I compare arriveDate1 to holiday they are not equal and I'm not sure why. In the console both dates appear the same. Any ideas why this might be? (using Date.js).

```
var orderShip1 = Date.today(); //date it ships
var arriveDate1 = orderShip1.addDays(3); //first day it could arrive

var holiday = Date.parse('8/8/2014');

console.log(arriveDate1); // Fri Aug 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) 
console.log(holiday);     // Fri Aug 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) 

if (arriveDate1 === holiday) {

    orderShip1.addDays(1);
    //arriveDate1 = orderShip1.addDays(1);   
}
```

Comment: You are comparing objects with `===` so they will never be the same unless you compare an object to itself. Use `==` instead, or convert to primitives e.g. `+arriveDate1 === +holiday`. What library are you using? *addDays* is not part of ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you check with the `==` and `===` operators, Javascript performs a check by reference. This two objects, unless they are declared like `holiday = arriveDate1`, will then never be equal, because they don't share the same memory reference.

Example:

```
a = {foo: 'hello'};
b = {foo: 'hello'};
a == b;
> false
```

You should perform the check using `.toISOString` or the unary operator `+` to convert the data objects in milliseconds, like this:

```
// this
if (arriveDate1.toISOString() == holiday.toISOString()) ...
// or this
if (+arriveDate1 == +holiday) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The triple equals sign tests if objects are identical, that is they are the same object. Try double equals.

Comment: Triple and double equals make check by reference, so comparing two objects will always yield false, unless you declare one of them assigning to it the other one, like `obj1 = obj2`.